# PDFBox in Java trying to Edit Pdf with existing acroForms but values are hidden untill i press on them

Tags: java, pdf, nestjs, field, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox to get a document that was already generated from a Nestjs using PDF-lib js via the command form.createTextField(field.id); after that i send it to java so i can but a signature box ontop of it and fill the forms now the forms are filled and everything works with pdf viewer js
i can see the fields and the values but when i try to open the pdf file in google chrome i dont see the values at all or when i try to open that in Adobe reader i dont see the values untill i click on the field

here is my java code

```
public void prepareForSigning(DigestAlgorithm digestAlgorithm,
        SignatureType signatureType,
        UserData userData, List<FieldInput> formFields) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    this.digestAlgorithm = digestAlgorithm;
    id = Utils.generateDocumentId();
    pdDocument = PDDocument.load(contentIn);

    int accessPermissions = getDocumentPermissions();
    if (accessPermissions == 1) {
        throw new AisClientException("Cannot sign document [" + name + "]. Document contains a certification " +
                "that does not allow any changes.");
    }

    // add fields
    // get the document catalog
    try {
        PDAcroForm acroForm = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
        acroForm.setSignaturesExist(true);
        acroForm.setAppendOnly(true);
        acroForm.getCOSObject().setDirect(true);
        acroForm.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
        // acroForm.setNeedAppearances(true);
        COSObject pdfFields = acroForm.getCOSObject().getCOSObject(COSName.FIELDS);
        if (pdfFields != null) {
            pdfFields.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < formFields.size(); i++) {
            PDField field = acroForm.getField(formFields.get(i).id);
            if (field != null) {
                // will also set a checkbox if the value is Yes
                // checking for formFields.get(i).value == "true" returns
                if (field.getFieldType() == "Btn" && formFields.get(i).value.equals("true")) {
                    field.setValue("Yes");
                } else {
                    field.setValue(formFields.get(i).value);
                }
                field.setReadOnly(true);
                field.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
                field.getWidgets().get(0).getAppearance().getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
                Log.info("set field: " + field.getFullyQualifiedName() + " to " + formFields.get(i).value);
            }
        }
       
        pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.warn(e);
    }

    PDSignature pdSignature = new PDSignature();
    Calendar signDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (signatureType == SignatureType.TIMESTAMP) {
        // Now, according to ETSI TS 102 778-4, annex A.2, the type of a Dictionary that
        // holds document timestamp should be DocTimeStamp
        // However, adding this (as of Feb/17/2021), it trips the ETSI Conformance
        // Checked online tool, making it say
        // "There is no signature dictionary in the document". So, for now (Feb/17/2021)
        // this has been removed. This makes the
        // ETSI Conformance Checker happy.
        // pdSignature.setType(COSName.DOC_TIME_STAMP);
        pdSignature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
        pdSignature.setSubFilter(COSName.getPDFName("ETSI.RFC3161"));
    } else {
        pdSignature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
        pdSignature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ETSI_CADES_DETACHED);
        // Add 3 Minutes to move signing time within the OnDemand Certificate Validity
        // This is only relevant in case the signature does not include a timestamp
        // See section 5.8.5.1 of the Reference Guide
        signDate.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 3);
    }

    pdSignature.setSignDate(signDate);
    pdSignature.setName(userData.getSignatureName());
    pdSignature.setReason(userData.getSignatureReason());
    pdSignature.setLocation(userData.getSignatureLocation());
    pdSignature.setContactInfo(userData.getSignatureContactInfo());

    SignatureOptions options = new SignatureOptions();
    options.setPreferredSignatureSize(signatureType.getEstimatedSignatureSizeInBytes());

    // create a visible signature at the specified coordinates
    if (signatureDefinition != null) {
        Rectangle2D humanRect = new Rectangle2D.Float(signatureDefinition.getX(),
                signatureDefinition.getY(),
                signatureDefinition.getWidth(),
                signatureDefinition.getHeight());
        PDRectangle rect = createSignatureRectangle(pdDocument, humanRect);
        options.setVisualSignature(
                createVisualSignatureTemplate(pdDocument, signatureDefinition.getPage(),
                        signatureDefinition.getImage(), rect, pdSignature));
        options.setPage(signatureDefinition.getPage());
    }

    pdDocument.addSignature(pdSignature, options);
    // Set this signature's access permissions level to 0, to ensure we just sign
    // the PDF, not certify it
    // for more details:
    // https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf
    // see section 12.7.4.5
    setPermissionsForSignatureOnly();

    pbSigningSupport = pdDocument.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(inMemoryStream);

    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(digestAlgorithm.getDigestAlgorithm());
    byte[] contentToSign = IOUtils.toByteArray(pbSigningSupport.getContent());
    byte[] hashToSign = digest.digest(contentToSign);
    options.close();
    base64HashToSign = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hashToSign);
}
```

now the field with value 5 is appearing because i already clicked on it which is on focus() mode
adobe reader

when i use acoForm.setNeedAppearances to true i can then see the values but then the signature field is not there am i missing something in code ?

i am expecting to see the values in google chrome or Adobe Reader appearing without me pressing on them

[Picture of the pdf fields without values with one field being focused on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg3Wl.png)

[PDF SAMLE FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EJ8ra5dC5R4mx8-HacGrVbtQAWBQzUq9/view?usp=sharing%22%3EPdf%20Samle%20File)

Comment: Please don't submit your code as an image. Use `these code tags`

Comment: Also please share an example PDF processed by your code for analysis.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @mkl i uploded the pdf sample

Comment: In your PDF the text widget annotation is not merged with the text field. If you want to store the updated appearance of the annotation, you also have to mark the widget annotation object as updated. Or you have to collect the updated appearance objects and use `saveIncremental(OutputStream output, Set<COSDictionary> objectsToWrite)`.

Comment: @mkl i have submitted the full method i use saveIncrementalForExternalSigning with the stream

Comment: Ok, in that case please try to also mark the widget annotation object as updated.

Comment: @mkl thank you so much for your responses! , how would i then achieve that ?

Comment: `field.getWidgets().get(0).getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);`